# Can there exist two identical Hubble volumes?

Tags: cosmology, universe

It is written that in our Universe (if it's very large and maybe infinite) there can be two (or more) [Hubble volumes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubble_volume) with exactly the same configurations of particles in phase space.

Now imagine two exactly the same Hubble volumes. Two persons (copies of each other) who live in the middle of those volumes look with a super telescope to the edge of their volumes. Then they don't see the same thing because their neighbour Hubble volumes are different. So they are *not* exact copies of each other, contradicting the assumption that their Hubble volumes are identical. Is this proof that no two identical Hubble volumes exist (because they interact with neighbour Hubble volumes)?

Comment: Hi, could you check the Wikipedia link in your post,it goes  nowhere when I click on it, might be my tablet though, thanks.

Comment: The link in Wikipedia says to search some more, there's no such article.

Comment: @Countto10-Hi there! I don't understand why you don't get it! If I click on the link I'm lead directly to the Wikipedia page for a Hubble volume.

Answer (score 2):

If the observers both look to the edge of their Hubble volumes, then they will both see nothing. Anything beyond the edge of a Hubble volume is receding faster than the speed of light, so light will never reach the observers. It is impossible to see into a neighboring Hubble volume or interact with them in any other way.

There is a complication due to the universe expanding or contracting, and whether these changes are accelerating and decelerating, as that allows objects to cross from inside to outside a Hubble volume and back.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose they look at something between themselves and the surface of their Hubble volume. Surely they both can see something. But how can they see the same thing? Light from a neighbouring volume could have reached the two pieces of space they are looking at, and because the light from the different neighbour Hubble volumes is different in both volumes, our two friends don't see the same image, so both are not copies of one another, contradicting the assumption that there can be two identical Hubble volumes